# insert node in a linked list runtime error

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list

the code is supposed to add a node after the previous node argument, given the city name and the head pointer.  I get a runtime error, however, when I run the code, why?

```
 city* addCity(city *head, city *previous, string cityName )
    {
        city* add = new city;
        add->name=cityName;
        add->next = NULL;
        city* tmp = new city;
        tmp = head;


        if(tmp==NULL){
            tmp = add;
        }

        while(tmp != NULL && tmp != previous){
            tmp = head;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }


    if(tmp == previous){
        add->next = previous->next;
        tmp->next = add;
        head = tmp;
        return head;
        } 


        }
```

Comment: Can you please post the error message !

Comment: `city* tmp = new city; tmp = head;` This will cause a memory leak in your program.

Comment: It's a singly linked list. I am running the code on an online platform, i'll send you a screenshot of the error shortly

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure if I can post images since I am a new user.

Comment: U can make this code lot more easier. No need to do all these things. Wait I'll share the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too much complication.

You have two general cases: either you're given the `previous` node in the list, so you *don't have to seek it*, or `previous == NULL` and you insert the new node at the front of the list (which also covers the case of an empty list).

```
city* addCity(city *head, city *previous, string cityName)
{
    city *newcity = new city;
    newcity->name = cityName;

    if (previous != NULL)
    {
        newcity->next = previous->next;
        previous->next = newcity;
    }
    else
    {
        newcity->next = head;
        head = newcity;
    }

    return head;
}
```

Note the `return` statement – your function has no access to the original `head` of the list, so the only way to inform the code outside that a new node appeared at the front of the list is returning a pointer to it. Of course, if a new node is inserted somewhere inside the list or appended at the end, the head doesn't change and the returned value equals the input `head`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this worked. I am kinda new to data structures, do you have suggestions as to how become more familiar with it?

Answer (score 1):

```
  while(tmp != NULL && tmp != previous){
        tmp = head;
        tmp = tmp->next;
  }
```

This will run infinite times as `tmp` is reset to `head` in each iteration. `tmp` is just toggling  in a cyclic way between values `head` and `head->next` in this loop.

Comment: Not necessarily infinite. At the beginning, the list is probably empty, `head==NULL`, so the `tmp` variable is assigned the `add` value before the above loop. Then the loop will enter the first iteration (due to `tmp != NULL`) and most probably crash on accessing `tmp->next` after `tmp=head` (i.e.: `NULL`) assignment.

Answer (score 0):

> If you have the previous node that contain the next the node and the String you can directly add the new node to that.

Try this

```
city* addCity(city *head, city *previous, string cityName ){
    city* add = new city;
    add->name=cityName;
    if (head == NULL || previous == NULL){
        add->next = head ;
        return add;
    }
    add->next = previous->next;
    previous->next = add;
    return head;
}
```

**This is enough too achieve the same ans.**

For the first node to create check the following example

```
void Cites(){
    city *head = new city();
    head = addCity(head, head ,"First city name");
    //Do the rest of the codes
}
```

**Edited:** Now this code will work even to add node in the first. by passing previous as NULL

Comment: For the first code, you would get "nothing in path". The second one a run time error :/.

Comment: For the updated code, if you add a member in the beginning of the list you would end up with a runtime error. But it works if the new city was in the middle of the linked list.

Comment: == CURRENT PATH ==
Los Angeles -> Phoenix -> Denver -> Dallas -> Atlanta -> New York ->  NULL
===

***Runtime error***

Comment: I am using moodle to submit the code and instead of the runtime error message we're supposed to update the linked list and put a city before LosAngeles in this case

Comment: @MahmoudAlmansouri You need to insert before or after the previous node ?

Comment: After the previous node :)

Comment: @MahmoudAlmansouri Please Paste the function calling statement here. Check weather you pass the correct parameters,

Comment: "Construct default setup, print network, then add "Monterey" as the first city, and print network" This is the statement that's testing it on moodle.  So I think previous in this case should equal to NULL.

Comment: @MahmoudAlmansouri If you are adding the first node then pass the parameters as head = addCity(NULL, NULL, "Name"); This will return a new head pointer location  to the head.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you mean by pass the parameters as head = addcity(NULL,NULL,"Name"); but I was thinking about an if statement as follows (if previous ==NULL): the first element in the list should be the cityname. what do you think?

Comment: What i meant is if the head is NULL that is u created a head but its not Initialized as city *head = new city(); in the calling function. then u can call the addCity function as head = addCity(head,head,"City Name"); that is for the first time head should be NULL;

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! You're awesome.

Comment: How does your code handle inserting a new item _in front_ of the list (i.e. _before_ the first item)?

Comment: @CiaPan U mean for the first node ?. That is for inserting the first node when the list is empty?. If this is the case it will easily handle this code. If there is nothing in the item. the head will be NULL. So am changing the head pointer to Add variable. and returning the new location to the calling function. example; ActualHead = NULL; Add->123(location) head = add = 123; returning head => returning 123; The actualHead will become 123

Comment: No, I wrote 'in front of the list', not 'into an empty list'. I also wrote 'before the first item', which means there exists some 'first item', so the list is _not_ empty.

Comment: The actual problem was to insert an item after the previous you can refer the previous comment. @CiaPan

Comment: @MahmoudAlmansouri Code is modified to insert item in the front of list

Comment: @CiaPan Code is modified to insert item in the front of list

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of issues.

**Firstly,**

```
city* tmp = new city;
tmp = head;
```

Your are creating a new city for `tmp` but immediately assigning it to `head`. Assuming you just need a `*tmp`, so you can change `city *tmp = new city;` to `city *tmp = head;`

**Then,**

```
if(tmp==NULL){
    tmp = add;
}
```

`tmp == NULL` means the list is empty. So you should add the new city to `head` and simply return from there.
So, your code should be-

```
if(tmp==NULL){
    head = add;
    return head;
}
```

**Continuing,**

```
while(tmp != NULL && tmp != previous){
    tmp = head;
    tmp = tmp->next;
}
```

This is an infinite loop if `tmp` is not `NULL`. Because your are doing the same things in each iteration. It should be like-

```
tmp = head;

while(tmp != NULL || tmp != previous){
    tmp = tmp->next;
}
```

**Forwarding,**

```
if(tmp == previous){
    add->next = previous->next;
    tmp->next = add;
    head = tmp;
    return head;
}
```

I don't know why you are assigning `tmp` to `head`. Just removing `head = tmp;` should solve a lot of issues.